# While sending 25MB file continuously 5 to 10 times I am getting below exception through javamail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtpclient, exchange-server-2010

Getting Below Error:

DEBUG SMTP: IOException while sending, closing, THROW:
    java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe**
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the SMTP server's way of telling you it doesn't like you to blast that amount of data in that short a time.

Have you seen the server logs on the smtp?

Comment: Thanks for replying.I have not look the smtp logs. I will check that and is there is a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Bvyas You can change the bandwidth usage limit set on the server, or send the data at a more moderate rate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Posting your reply.
I identify the problem and solution of it.
My Exchange server has max timeout is 10 min and I am sending bulk email with of 30 mb message and tricky thing is I am running with setting transport.setDebug(true) which cause the issue.